# How to fix "The message port closed before a response was received." after window.location.reload() in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm having an issue with javascript, since chrome v73.0.3683.86, whenever I run my javascript code after window.location.reload() function it always give me the error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."

I've searching for many topics over the internet but most of it is about chrome extension. So I tried to run this code in cognito mode and disable all extension but there's no changes.

※For some reason I need to run something after window.location.reload()

onClick javascript function like this

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello world!</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function buttonClick() {
                window.location.reload();
                document.title = "Hi there";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <button onclick="buttonClick()">Click here</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `For some reason I need to run something after window.location.reload()` - well, your whole design is flawed. Once you reload the page, the code after that is irrelevant

Comment: Oh surprises! @JaromandaX I thought exactly like you and then went to try location.reload();navigator.sendBeacon('foo') on my localhost, and on my server's logs I can clearly see the request is executed. And actually even `location.reload(); localStorage.executesAfter="true";` will work.

Comment: @OP, do you see this message when running the code snippet in your question? 73.0.3683.86 on macOS here, an I got nothing.

Comment: @Kaiido - yes, that works ... but that's not what the OP wants to do, he wants to change the title of the page after unloading it?

Comment: Thanks guys, but I'm looking for an explaination about "The message port closed before a response was received"

@Jaromanda: Yes, the design is not good, it works well before chrome version 73 though :(

Comment: `The message port closed` well, what is the message port? is the html in your question the whole page, nothing more to it than that? because the code in the question does not produce the error you report in firefox or chrome

Comment: My guess is, you have some web extension that is causing that error - disable all web extensions, if the error goes away, then you can enable them one by one until the error occurs

Comment: The error message appear only when it's run in localhost

Comment: @JaromandaX you are right!, It's because of an extension that I can not disable in by browser, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to run it on chrome without any extension?
- Right click on your Chrome shortcut
- Select Properties.
- Add to the end of the Target field --disable-extensions --disable-plugins

It will look like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1 --disable-extensions --disable-plugins
```

- Click on OK
- Start Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Thank guys, I figured out the problem, it's because of an extension try to send message to it's background.js by running "chrome.runtime.sendMessage"
Therefore when I run the windown.location.onload() function, it's close the message port and throw out the error message!

The problem is that extension can not be disabled on my office computer :))

Answer (score 0):

Disable all the extensions you installed on the Chrome browser. This worked for me and I saw that many people said it worked.

Hope this works for you too.

If you can't disable the extensions, you can hide the error message in console.
Go to console and uncheck the "Errors" under the "Custom levels" right after the Filter. See the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, disable all the extensions - and lose needed capabilities, not really a solution, especially if that goes against corporate policies. Turning off off errors would be fine if that could be limited to just that message from just that extension, otherwise, all other errors, including those generated by the OP developer, will be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this one is a kinda different, not totally related with the problem in the OP. But if you are having a trouble with a button click then here is a reminder.

```html
   <button type="button"></button>
```

This might happen, If you are wrapping the *button* in a *form* element. The default behavior of a button inside a form element is "submit". So change it to "button" if the button is not trying to submit formdata.